# SQL Databricks - LAG function BY distinct values

Tags: sql, window-functions, databricks-sql

I have a table with two columns (number and id) and would like to calculate value_needed column.

Column definition - replace 8 by previous number + 1.

But by using simple LAG function I receive that output:

| number | id | value_current | value_needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 123 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 123 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 123 | 3 | 3 |
| 8 | 123 | 9 | 3 |

I need to achive value_needed column (for all 8 have '3' as an output)

My code :

```
CASE WHEN number = 8 
           THEN LAG(number) OVER (PARTITION BY (id) ORDER BY number) + 1
           ELSE number
```

I need to define that in CASE statement without WHERE condition. I've tried to add case when to partition by but it doesn't work properly

Comment: Given your sample data (these 5 rows) can you share what your desired results would be. I'm having difficulty understanding what *"replace maximum value of number by previous number + 1."* means.

Comment: I need to replace '8' by (max(number) over partition by id) + 1 but excluding 8 in the calculation. So for each 8 I need to have 3 (2+1) cause maximum number is 2 for a given ID.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the clarification. That makes sense.

Comment: I'm not convinced this exactly what you are looking for, but given your data and the desired output, it sounds like `DENSE_RANK()` is the agg window function you want: `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY number)` If the requirement is more complicated than your sample data lets on, please feel free to edit the question to include that.

Comment: thanks, you're right ! I used DANSE_RANK and deleted '+1' and works perfectly

Comment: Oh great! I've added as an answer to tie this one up.

Answer (score 0):

Given your data and the desired output, it sounds like DENSE_RANK() is the agg window function you want:

```
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY number)
```

An example using your sample data:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 1 as num, 123 as id 
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 123
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 123
  UNION ALL SELECT 8, 123 
  UNION ALL SELECT 8, 123 
)
SELECT num, id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY num) as value_needed
FROM cte
```

Results:

```
+-----+-----+--------------+
| num | id  | value_needed |
+-----+-----+--------------+
|   1 | 123 |            1 |
|   1 | 123 |            1 |
|   2 | 123 |            2 |
|   8 | 123 |            3 |
|   8 | 123 |            3 |
+-----+-----+--------------+
```